# C++ regex header not registering for Netezza UDF

Tags: c++, regex, compiler-errors, include, netezza

I am compiling a UDF on IBM's Netezza using C++ as per the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.udf.doc/c_udf_create_udfs.html). My code compiles with no issues

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include "udxinc.h"
#include "udxhelpers.h"

using namespace nz::udx_ver2;

class Dateconvert: public Udf
{
public:
    Dateconvert(UdxInit *pInit) : Udf(pInit){}
    ~Dateconvert(){}

    static Udf* instantiate(UdxInit *pInit);
    virtual ReturnValue evaluate()
    {

      StringReturn* ret = stringReturnInfo();
      StringArg *str;
      str = stringArg(0);
      int lengths = str->length;
      char *datas = str->data;
      char retval[100];
      strcpy(retval,"99991231");

      ret->size = sizeof(retval);
      memcpy(ret->data, retval, sizeof(retval));

      NZ_UDX_RETURN_STRING(ret);
    }
};

Udf* Dateconvert::instantiate(UdxInit *pInit)
{
      return new Dateconvert(pInit);
}
```

I need to use regex to process the string argument with some regular expression logic. However, when I try to add in

```
#include <regex>
```

or

```
#include <regex.h>
```

And the code regex-specific code:

```
string int_num= "some pattern"
string test= "test"
regex pattern(int_num);
if(regex_match(test, pattern) { do something};
```

I get the following errors:

```
/nz/kit.7.2.0.7-P1/sys/cc/bin/i686-rhel5-linux-gnu-g++ -o 
/export/home/nz/DateConvert.o_x86  -fPIC -shared -Wa,--32 -march=prescott
-mfpmath=sse -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DGENCODE -DNZDEBUG=0 -DNZ_UDX_COMPILE 
-I/nz/kit.7.2.0.7-P1/sys/include -I/nz/kit.7.2.0.7-P1/sys/include/pg/include
-DLINUX   /export/home/nz/DateConvert.cpp
/export/home/nz/DateConvert.cpp:3:17: error: regex: No such file or directory
/export/home/nz/DateConvert.cpp: In member function 'virtual nz::udx::ReturnValue Dateconvert::evaluate()':
/export/home/nz/DateConvert.cpp:27: error: 'regex' was not declared in this scope
/export/home/nz/DateConvert.cpp:27: error: expected `;' before 'pattern'
/export/home/nz/DateConvert.cpp:45: error: 'pattern' was not declared in this scope
/export/home/nz/DateConvert.cpp:45: error: 'regex_match' was not declared in this scope
```

Every online example uses these two headers for regex in c++. Why is it not registering when I compile?

This is the compile command by the way:

```
nzudxcompile /export/home/nz/dateconvert.cpp -o dateconvert.o 
--sig "Dateconvert(VARCHAR(200))" --version 2 --return "VARCHAR(200)" 
--class Dateconvert --user user1 --pw pw1  --db db1
```

Comment: `using std::regex;`.

Comment: Does this mean append "std::regex" to any regex related code, or to add "using namespace std::regex" to the top of the code? @AlanStokes

Comment: You can add the line I gave at the top of the code (`regex` is a name, not a namespace). Or explicitly put `std::` in front of `regex`.

Comment: Adding "using std::regex;" under "using namespace nz::udx_ver2;" gives the error "error: 'std::regex' has not been declared" @AlanStokes

Comment: You need `#include <regex>` too, before the using. Without the ".h".

Comment: I have tried that. Same error. Does it matter than string and strdarg have the ".h"? Not sure what else it could be. @AlanStokes

Comment: Sorry, no idea. std::regex should be in `<regex>`. You haven't got that, so there is something very wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not my area of expertise, but it looks to me as if the included regex.h for Netezza UDX development is from the GNU C library which would use regcomp and regexec, rather than regex_match.

The header has an ifdef block for cpp support.

There are a couple of Netezza UDF samples using these functions [here](https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/wikis/home?lang=en-us#!/wiki/W361a40e2ccf0_43c7_b802_e51fcadaec6b/page/C__%20UDX%20Examples).